# Trying to get Ruby/Rails installed on OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

This is my first question please be nice.

I've been trying to get my hands dirty with ruby/rails for a small coding project. I have Mountain Lion, and have been trying to use various techniques i've found on stackoverflow, and across the interwebs. It's not going so great! Nothing works of course. I have the system version of Ruby (1.8.7) as of now, and a bunch of broken junk from trying and failing to install Ruby!

When I install Rails via gem install, it sat for awhile... I finally learned to use -V, and noticed everything was returning back 302, and this takes forever, and finally it installs -- I get this output when I try to run rails -v

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:230:in `activate': can't activate rack (~> 1.4.5, runtime) for ["actionpack-3.2.13", "railties-3.2.13"], already activated rack-1.5.2 for ["rack-ssl-1.3.3", "railties-3.2.13"] (Gem::LoadError)

It looks like some dependencies are broken?  Anyhow I'm now trying to use RVM now to get another version of ruby and setup grails with brew, This is telling me that I need a newer version of ruby to install anything pretty much?? Here is the output.

rvm install 1.9.2-head
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Skipping `brew update` make sure your formulas are up to date.
Cowardly refusing to continue, please read 'rvm autolibs'.

To proceed rvm requires a ruby-1.9|ruby-2 compatible ruby is installed.
We attempted to install ruby automatically but it failed.
Please install it manually (or a compatible alternative) to proceed.

-- I am getting os frustrated here, please throw me a bone and help me out --- If I have to have to I'll setup a linux vm just to get rails running -- yet I prefer working on my mac.

Please any advice?? I just want a working version of Rails 3 on my Mac this is allThanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please go through www.railsinstaller.org for detailed installation and setup process. This guide should answer all of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-install-ruby-on-a-mac/
The tutorial includes all the errors you may come across during the installation.
According to this tutorial Ruby on Rail comes with the mac out of the box.

Comment: I looked at this and tried -- They stopped including Rails with Lion and up I guess. when I tried using rails it told me to install the gem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried JewelryBox? It provides a painless install method for rvm and a great little gui that helps you monitor the size of your gem sets, and installs of ruby. Along with helpful reminders to upgrade rvm. I resisted at first using it, because using a GUI made me feel like a noob, but it really is a great little tool, that makes for super easy installs of ruby, and rvm, and consequently rails.

http://jewelrybox.unfiniti.com/

Comment: Thanks for the comment -- I actually did.. After I chose and install a Ruby, the console output on the panel just goes away (and it fails). I think my Mac is cursed. I actually caved in and setup a VM in Ubuntu with Ruby/Rails stack. Of course this took me all of 20 minutes. DOH!